# Wowza live streaming is not working for ionic application

Tags: wowza

Hi anyone implemented WOWZA live streaming for ionic framework and any help that how can we start recording of particular stream that i started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should start with reading documentation from 
https://www.wowza.com/docs/wowza-streaming-cloud-rest-api
site

It's also

https://info.wowza.com/trial-getting-started-play-a-live-stream